# Passing structure to a procedure as ByValue, however the procedure changes original structure values

Tags: vb.net, structure, byval

I want to ask something about VB.NET code. I'm suffering from this problem a lot. Please answer me if you know the solution of my question or give me some comments.

---

```
'Declare a structure "Gene"
    Public Structure Gene
    Dim Seq() As Integer
    End Structure

'Here is a procedure, it changes original value.
        Public Sub Mutation(ByVal OriginalGene As Gene, ByRef TargetGene As Gene)
        Dim P1 As Integer
        Dim P2 As Integer
        Dim Temp As Integer

        P1 = Int((N_Jobs - 1 + 1) * Rnd(RndNum) + 0)
        P2 = Int((N_Jobs - 1 + 1) * Rnd(RndNum + 1) + 0)

        TargetGene.Seq = OriginalGene.Seq

        Temp = TargetGene.Seq(P1)
        TargetGene.Seq(P1) = TargetGene.Seq(P2)
        TargetGene.Seq(P2) = Temp
        End Sub
```

Comment: The `Gene` is passed by value, but one of the members is a reference to an array, so you are passing a reference by value, which is still a reference. Suppose I have a sheet of paper with an account number on it. I photocopy the paper and give it to you (pass by value) You withdraw money from the account. I go to the account and see that money was withdrawn, even though I passed the paper by value.

Comment: Thank you, I totally understand the problem because of your metaphor. Then what I can do for preventing the original array to be changed?

Comment: You can pass a copy, or you can pass a read only interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually changing the structure. All the structure contains is a pointer to an array. The reference to the array is always the same even though you can have an unlimited number of copies of the structure.

---

Example of immutable Gene class:

```
Public Class Gene
    Private _sequence() As Integer
    Public Sub New(sequence() As Integer)
        _sequence = sequence
    End Sub
    Public Function GetSequence() As Integer()
        Return _sequence.Select(Function (x) x).ToArray()
    End Function
    Public Function Mutate() As Gene
        Dim sequence() As Integer = Me.GetSequence()

        Dim P1 As Integer
        Dim P2 As Integer
        Dim Temp As Integer

        P1 = Int((N_Jobs - 1 + 1) * Rnd(RndNum) + 0)
        P2 = Int((N_Jobs - 1 + 1) * Rnd(RndNum + 1) + 0)

        TargetGene.Seq = OriginalGene.Seq

        Temp = sequence(P1)
        sequence(P1) = sequence(P2)
        sequence(P2) = Temp

        Return New Gene(sequence)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What can I do for not changing the OriginalGene in my procedure?

Comment: You're going to have to make the array private and then provide methods to access the data that are read-only. Any code that changes the array needs to return a new structure/class with a new array with the updated values.

Comment: It is somehow hard for me to understand perfectly. Could you give me a brief example?

Comment: I've added a sample class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really helpful for studying VB.Net code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the copy of the structure, try something like:

```
    Structure Gene
    Dim Seq() As Integer
    Public Function Clone() As Gene
        Dim mySt As Gene
        Array.Copy(Me.Seq, mySt.Seq, Me.Seq.Length)
        Return mySt
    End Function
End Structure
```

And then instead of:

```
TargetGene.Seq = OriginalGene.Seq
```

use

```
TargetGene.Seq = OriginalGene.Clone()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the sequence is fixed, you may be able to use a `fixed` array declaration to hold it, but fixed arrays require "unsafe" code which may be problematic in some cases.

Otherwise, there's really no nice way for a structure to encapsulate a non-fixed collection with value semantics.  If one wishes to have the structure convey the illusion of encapsulating a collection with mutable value semantics, one must have the structure hold a private reference to an array or other data type which will never change once a reference has been stored into a struct field.  If the structure is asked to change the contained data, it must create a new object which encapsulates the changed data.  Note that any changes which are ever going to be made must take place before storing the reference.

A further difficulty with having structures provide mutable value semantics is that there is no means via which instance methods on a structure can indicate whether they may be safely employed on read-only structure instances.  In reality, no structure methods or properties may be used on read-only structure instances, but if C# sees, e.g.

```
 someObject.propertyOfStructType.doSomething();
```

it will silently rewrite the code as

```
 var temp = someObject.propertyOfStructType;
 temp.doSomething();
```

Sometimes that substitution is safe.  Sometimes it isn't.  Although it should be simple for a compiler to check whether a method is tagged with a "not for use on read-only structures" attribute and refuse to employ the above substitution with such methods, no attribute for such purpose has been documented.  Consequently, if one wants to provide a safe means of e.g. copying a range of values from an array into a value-array type, one must write and invoke the method as something like:

```
public static int LoadFromEnumerable(ref ValueArray<T> it, int startIndex, IEnumerable<T> source);

int numElementsAdded = ValueArray<int>.LoadFromEnumerable(ref myValueArray, 4, myIntegers);
```

as opposed to the much cleaner-looking

```
public int LoadFromEnumerable(int startIndex, IEnumerable<T> source);

myValueArray.LoadFromEnumerable(4, myIntegers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You gave me a lot of information about VB.Net.